# Display Page Title→ Site Name and, Site Tagline

Tags: wordpress, title

This has probably been asked a number of times before but I'm struggling to find a nice clean way to display the Page Title, followed by the Site Name, followed by the Site Description on all pages except the homepage, where I'd like it to just say Site Name and Tagline, to clarify...

Homepage
Site Name | Site Tagline

All other pages
Page Name | Site Name

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that will assign the title

```
function my_custom_title() {
    $sitename = get_option('blogname');
    $tagline = get_option('blogdescription');
    if ( is_front_page()  ) { // For Front Page
        echo '<title>'.$sitename.' | '. $tagline.'</title>';
    } elseif( is_page() || is_single() ) { // For Post/ Post
        echo '<title>'.get_the_title(). ' | '. $sitename.'</title>';
    } else { //Other pages like archive, taxonomy, tags, category,etc
        echo '<title>'.$sitename. ' | '. $sitename.'</title>';
    }
}
```

You can then hook that function on wp_head or add it directly on header.php